# How to know the kinetic rate of one reaction from 3 tests with different concentrations?

Tags: kinetics, concentration

Recently, I've run an experiment about the effect of reducing concentration on rate of a reaction.

Here's the chemical reaction:

$\ce{10 NaHSO3 + 4 KIO3 ⇌ 5 Na2SO4 + 2 I2 + 3 H2SO4 + 2 K2SO4 + 2 H2O}$

I ran three tests:

> 1. $10$ cc $\ce{KIO3}$ Solution + $10$ cc $\ce{NaHSO3}$ solution _ Time: $163$ sec
> 2. $10$ cc $\ce{KIO3}$ Solution + A $6$ cc $\ce{NaHSO3}$ and $4$ cc water solution _ Time: $320$ sec
> 3. $10$ cc $\ce{KIO3}$ Solution + A $4$ cc $\ce{NaHSO3}$ and $6$ cc water solution _ Time: $713$ sec

I calculated the molarity of $\ce{NaHSO3}$ in each test and also calculated the rate of each test using the formula : $\frac{[\ce{NaHSO3}]}{t}$

Now the question is how can I know the kinetic order of this reaction?

I mean with only 3 numbers of concentration, I cannot draw a curve. Is there any other way to know the kinetic order?

Edit: I hope you already know that the curve of concentration according to time shows the kinetic order of reaction. It's just with 3 data you cannot draw an accurate curve.

Comment: Is cc an abbreviation for cubic centimetre, i.e. mL?

Comment: Yes cc is cubic centimitre, maybe I should've  written mL (mililitre).

Comment: What do  the times you give represent ? How did you obtain them?

Comment: The time to see the I2 blue colour. It means by reducing the concentration of NaHSO3, the rate of reaction also reduces. In other words, it takes more time to see the result. I've already said I ran the tests myself.

Comment: Are you allowing for the possibility of a complex reaction mechanism and thus a fractional or negative reaction order? If not and you are just trying to choose between zero, first, and second order, it would seem to be closest to linear.

Comment: zero order is linear, but first and second are not. In first order log[A] and in second 1/[A] is linear. The point is my data is only 3 concentration, few in my opinion, and on the other side the numbers are experimental, I mean resulted from a simple kinetic test. Based on 3 numbers, I cannot draw an accurate curve to make sure of the order of reaction above.

Comment: @Crimson-Ruby I realize I was misreading your data as rates instead of times. This would change my conclusion to closer to second. You can compute reaction order without a graph, its a commonly assigned problem in general chemistry courses (see [example 4](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Experimental_Methods/Methods_of_Determining_Reaction_Order)on chemlibre). The main problems you have see seem to be that experimental error can skew the results away from a perfect linear fit and you don't consider the possibility that the reaction has a complex.

Comment: (continued) dependence on the concentration. Your reaction could just as easily have a fractional, negative, or mixed order dependence on concentration (see the wikipedia page for [reaction order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_reaction)).

Comment: I see. So actually my data may be nearly accurate and still the graph may not be linear. There was a formula by which I could calculate the order of reaction in proportion to [NaHSO3] : log(R1/R2)/log(A]1/[A]2 But that doesn't give me the order of whole reaction, unless and as I think it is, order in proportion to [KIO3] is zero.